# Как реализовать вложенные компоненты

Tags: компоненты, blazor

Пытаюсь разобраться как реализовать вложенность компонентов примерно такой структуры:
Первый компонент:

```
    <div id='mainComponent'>
    </div>
```

И второй компонент:

```
     <div id='nestedComponent'>
    </div>
```

Хотелось бы использовать структуру типа

```
    <mainComponent>
          <nestedComponent>          
          </nestedComponent>         
    </mainComponent>
```

Но насколько я понимаю такая структура невозможна. Так ли это?
Как сделать так чтобы в родительском компоненте содержались дочерние? Правильно ли я понимаю,
что это можно сделать только внутри родительского компонента (внутри div родительского компонента)?
Хотел посмотреть где нибудь исходные коды реализации div элемента html , но пока не нашел

Comment: Я знаю что дочерний компонент можно вложить в родительский https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#child-content . Но это не совсем удобно. Допустим я сделал компонент карты, а затем хочу внутри него как в div расположить другие компоненты. Хотя ясно что это не возможно

Answer (score 3):

1. Заводите свойство `[Parameter]  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }`
2. Определяете где ему быть в разметке родителя.

```
<div>В меня вложили @ChildContent !</div>
```

3. Используете

```
<MyComponentWithChildContent>какую-то гадость</MyComponentWithChildContent>
<MyComponentWithChildContent>замечательную штуку</MyComponentWithChildContent>
```